# How to read the contents of window?

Tags: selenium

[image]

I'm using selemium IDE to record & replay the testcase. I've to read the contents of the below displayed window & write/move the same data into another file.

How can i do it ?

Comment: wouldn't do that with IDE if you have a bit of programming skills reach for the stars, switch to WebDriver

Comment: Can you please help me how to do that ?

Comment: Do you have previous knowledge in any programming language (Java?)

Comment: I know perl. I just tried with reading a value of a particular cell & stored it in some variable. But it requires huge process if i want to do that for whole window.

Comment: what about a screenshot? second way would be to iterate through the xpaths...

Comment: It's same about screenshot. Now i retrieved the value 'Name' & stored it in variable. Even i thought of iterating But xpath is different for different cells. is it possible to read/store the data of one complete row ?

Comment: that's kinda hard to answer- I did that via iterating over xpaths but you have to decide if that's possible..

Comment: @Jackie James: Using Programming it is Possible but first you describe more about what you want to achieve.